# What tax year do I claim a fellowship if it is on both the 2017 1098-T and the 2018 1042-S?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, international, scholarship, student

Note: I am an international student and receive a yearly 1042-S.

I got a fellowship in November 2017 but my University did not distribute the money until January 2018.  Because I am an international student, federal and state taxes were taken out of the fellowship when it was distributed in January 2018.

So:
- My 2017 1098-T includes the fellowship in Box #5.
- My 2018 1042-S will include the fellowship (it was not included in my 2017 1042-S).

I will need to claim a portion of the fellowship as income, do I:
1) Claim the portion in my 2017 taxes to match the 1098-T?
2) Claim the portion in my 2018 taxes to match the 1042-S?
3) Something else altogether?

Many thanks in advance for helping me --
Charlie